# android studio app, press home button while application is working

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development

I already developed android studio app.

However, when I pressed home button while playing app from my phone.(not android emulator)

Then start my app again, it shows splash activity first then shows one error.

like unfortunately, my app is stopped.

What I want to do is, when I pressed home button and start my app again,

then it should start from activity where I pressed home button.

don't show splash thing again.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant codes ? and also, when you get the error, if your phone is plugged in you should be able to get the actual error message from the output window in android studio, that would be helpful.

Comment: I downloaded apk file directly on my phone. I didn't put my usb in my computer. is that matter?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have problems with Activity lifecycle. I think [this link](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) could help you.

Comment: do I need to put every onpause, onrestart, onresume, etc methods in every activity?I putted only oncreate

Comment: Maybe you don't need override all methods. Please, add relevant code and error message from logcat.